# incorrect html produced using statements in razor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Have a list of items. Every 2 items should be encapsulated by a specific `<div class>`

I'm sure it's y logic that is incorrect but when I step through it shows that is happening but the end result is not as such.

Produced

[image]

Desired Results

```
<div class=row cells2">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
<div class=row cells2">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

Code

```
<div class="grid">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if ((itemPosition % 3)== 0)
        {
            @:<div class="row cells2">
        }

        <div class="cell">
            <div class="panel">
                <div class="heading">
                    <span class="title">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Position)</span>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <table class="table hovered striped bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Facility
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Specialty
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Availability
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Positions
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        @foreach (var subItem in item.Detail)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => subItem.Facility.Name)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelIem => subItem.Specialty)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelIem => subItem.Availability)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelIem => subItem.NumberOfPositions)</td>
                            </tr>  
                        }
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        if ((itemPosition % 3) == 0)
        {
            @:</div>
        }
        itemPosition++;
    }
</div>
```

***Update***

Results of changing modules 2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `itemPosition` is initalized with zero and change your modulus expression to

```
if ((itemPosition % 2)== 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to think through how this is being rendered. Within the forloop you want the div closed after the second item, *but*, you want it reopened *before* the third item.

Right now, you've actually got two problems. Your div is closing after the fourth/third item (depending on whether you're zero-indexed or not) and your div is opening before the fourth/third item.

What you actually want is to 1) zero-index your iterator if it's not already (modulus ops are much simpler with zero-indexes) and 2) place both the closing and opening of the div at the start of the for loop, checking for a modulus of 2:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if ((itemPosition % 2) == 0)
    {
        @:</div><div class="row cells2">
    }

    ...
```

Now, when it enters the third iteration (0, 1, 2), it will close and reopen the div before rendering the standard content. If you want to 1-index, then you would need to move this block to the bottom of the for loop.

Either way, though, you want to close and open in the same spot. While you can do it separately at the top and bottom, the logic is much trickier to ensure that you're closing and reopening at the same time. Otherwise, you end up with mismatch tags that cause the browser rendering to go nuts -- pretty much the situation you're in now.

**EDIT**

Confound it... I confused myself. I actually got that backwards. It's easier to go with 1-index and close and reopen at the bottom. That way the initial zero doesn't trigger the modulus condition (`0 % 2 == 0`). If you need or just want to zero index, then you just need to add an additional condition to cover yourself:

```
if (itemPosition != 0 && itemPostion % 2 == 0)
```

Comment: ok I understand the close and reopen part but what has me confused is the first run it's closing and then opening. What does it first close if `row cells2` hasn't been opened yet?

Comment: See my edit. That's the problem I was referring to. Either add the `itemPosition != 0` condition or use a 1-index and close and re-open at the bottom of the loop.

Comment: `<div class="grid">` shouldn't be closed until outside the loop. `<div class=row cells2">` should trigger on 0, 2, 4. and closed after 2 `<div class="cell"` have been added into `<div class="row cells2">1

Answer (score 0):

My personal take on this is that you've added logic to the View:

```
if ((itemPosition % 3)== 0)
{
  @:<div class="row cells2">
}
```

There is no way to unit test that the *group* size is 2.

I assume your model is like:

```
IEnumerable<MyClass>
```

(Personal Opinion: which I never try to send `IEnumerabe<>` down to to a view because as soon as you want to add a property, you have to make it a full class object, so might as well just future proof it)

Instead I would:

```
public class PeopleVM
{
  public int GroupSize { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, Person>> Groups  { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller:

```
var model = new PeopleVM();

model.GroupSize = 2;

model.Persons = db.Persons
  .Select((person, index) => new 
  {
    Index = (index + 1) / model.GroupSize,
    Person = person
  })
  .GroupBy(ip => ip.Index, ip => ip.Person);
  .ToList();

model.GroupSize = 2;
```

Now the view becomes extremely easy:

```
@model PeopleVM

@foreach(var group in Model.Groups)
{
  <div class=row cells@Model.GroupSize">
    @foreach (var person in group)
    {
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
    }
  </div>
}
```

It also means that you can change the number to whatever you want, in a single location and the model and view stay sync'd.

Answer (score 0):

If there must be no divs added if there are no cells and assuming itemPosition starts with 0, you can use this

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if ((itemPosition % 2)== 0)
    {
        @:<div class="row cells2">
    }

    ...HTML...

    itemPosition++;
    if ((itemPosition % 2) == 0)
    {
        @:</div>
    }
}
if ((itemPosition % 2) > 0)
{
    @:</div>
}
```

The idea is that when itemPosition is even, you open the tag. Increment has to happen before checking for the end tag, since you don't want to close immediately, only after the second one. And after the loop you have to check if the number of items was odd so you will definitely close the tag.

If there may be empty divs, it would be a bit simpler

```
<div class="row cells2">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    ...HTML...

    itemPosition++;
    if ((itemPosition % 2) == 0)
    {
        @:</div><div class="row cells2">
    }
}
</div>
```